# Replacing elements from a list and its sublists - part II

Tags: performance, beginner, lisp, scheme, sicp

This is sort of a follow-up to 
[Replacing elements from a list and its sublists](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115338/replacing-elements-from-a-list-and-its-sublists)
but now there are arbitrary numbers of words that would be replaced stored in a list.

> Now write substitute2 that takes a list, a list of old words, and a list of new words; the last two lists should be the same length. It should return a copy of the first argument, but with each word that occurs in the second argument replaced by the corresponding word of the third argument:

[source](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/61a-stuff/Reader/MRFall/hw.pdf)

Please review my code.

```
(define (substitute2 lst oldlst newlst)
    (define (maybe-swap elem oldlst newlst) 
        (cond ((null? oldlst) elem)
            ((equal? (car oldlst) elem) (car newlst))
        (else (maybe-swap elem (cdr oldlst) (cdr newlst)))))
        (if (list? lst)
            (map (lambda (elem) (substitute2 elem oldlst newlst)) lst)
    (if (= (length oldlst) (length newlst)) (maybe-swap lst oldlst newlst) (error "invalid length"))))
```

How can I make this code better and more efficient? Did I overuse define?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pretty good. I only see one issue and it's more code appearance than functional

#### Fix your spacing

You indentation isn't quite right and makes it a little hard to see what clauses line up where. Here's your same code slightly altered:

```
(define (substitute2 lst oldlst newlst)
    (define (maybe-swap elem oldlst newlst) 
        (cond ((null? oldlst) elem)
              ((equal? (car oldlst) elem) (car newlst))
              (else (maybe-swap elem (cdr oldlst) (cdr newlst)))))
    (if (list? lst)
        (map (lambda (elem) (substitute2 elem oldlst newlst)) lst)
        (maybe-swap lst oldlst newlst)))
```

I lined up the three `cond` clauses - and cleared up the fact that the `map` and `maybe-swap` both belong to the `if`. As-is, it kind of looks life the `if` is part of `maybe-swap`.

#### Make a swapper function

This is more for fun than it is necessarily a valuable suggestion (I have no idea if this is good or not). But one thing we can do is take `oldlst` and `newlst` and turn those into a swapper function - one that takes an elem and returns the correct substituted result. The code to build up such a swapper is pretty similar to your `maybe-swap` already:

```
(define (make-swapper oldlst newlst)
   (if (null? oldlst)
       (lambda (elem) elem)
       (lambda (elem)
          (if (equal? elem (car oldlst))
              (car newlst)
              ((make-swapper (cdr oldlst) (cdr newlst)) elem)))))
```

So then in `substitute2`, we just make one up front and call it:

```
(define (substitute2 lst oldlst newlst)
    (define swapper (make-swapper oldlst newlst))
    (define (substitute-impl lst)
        (if (list? lst)
            (map substitute-impl lst)
            (swapper lst)))
    (substitute-impl lst))
```